# Managing Linux Kernel Config Files in Revision control

Tags: version-control, git, configuration-management, linux-kernel

I am working on some Linux kernel drivers for a specific embedded system (NVIDIA Tegra X1). I am using the kernel source provided by NVIDIA (L4T), which has its own default kernel config files. My goal is to make some modifications to NVIDIA's kernel config file to support my new drivers.

The complication is that when I modify the default config with `make menuconfig` or `make nconfig`, the config file changes significantly. Based on my research, it seems like this is caused by nconfig and menuconfig filling in defaults for values that were not specified by the given loaded config file, and annotating options that are left unconfigured. I'm okay with that.

The problem is that NVIDIA is continually developing their kernel. If they add or change options in the default config, I want to be able to just merge those changes instead of comparing diffs to see what I need to update.

How can I manage my project's custom kernel config file in a way that allows me to easily integrate future changes pushed by NVIDIA?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `make savedefconfg` this will generate a `defconfig` file that should be close to the defconfig provided by nvidia. At least, the diff will be smaller.